# Xpath: Get Text After Element With Containing Text

Tags: html, xpath

I am looking for a way to get text which is not inside an HTML element:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <strong>Handelnde Personen:</strong><br><br>
  <strong>Geschäftsführer</strong><br>
  Mr John Doe<br>
  Privatperson<br>
  .....<br>
  <br>
```

I want to get "Mr John Doe".

The only way I see is looking for a strong element which contains "Geschäftsführer" and then look for the following text.

My idea so far:

> //strong[contains(text(), 'Gesch')]/br/../text()

... I simply can't make it work.

Also, is there a "wildcard" for strings? That I could use

```
*esch*ftsf*hr*
```

for "Geschäftsführer"?

I highly appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
//strong[starts-with(., 'Gesch')]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

As for wildcard matching, with XPath 2.0 you use regular expressions:

```
//strong[matches(., '.*esch.*ftsf.*hr.*')]
```

With XPath 3.0 you could also use the Unicode collation algorithm

```
//strong[compare(., 'Geschäftsführer', 
  'http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?strength=primary') = 0]
```

(strength=primary ignores case and accents)

But to get anything more advanced than XPath 1.0 in the browser, you would need to deploy Saxon-JS.

Another option with 1.0 is to use translate() to remove case and umlauts:

```
//strong[translate(., 'ABCD..XYZÄÖÜäöüß', 'abcd..xyzaouaous') = 'geschaftsfuhrer']
```

Note, in all these examples I have used `"."` rather than `"text()"` to get the string value of an element - this is recommended practice.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! Exactly what I needed. Regarding wildcard, is there a wildcard solution for Xpath 1.0?